# Problem with the BarChart3D function

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, charts

I have a list of values {x,y,z} and I would like to create a 3D bar chart with axis x,y,z .

```
test= {{1, 1, 0.0425421}, {1, 2, 0.0603692}, {1, 3, 0.0659077}, {1, 4, 
  0.0631829}, {1, 5, 0.0520746}, {1, 6, 0.035611}, {1, 7, 
  0.0176222}, {1, 8, -0.00627115}, {1, 9, -0.0293295}, {1, 
  10, -0.0542067}, {2, 1, 0.0495183}, {2, 2, 0.0650703}, {2, 3, 
  0.0667629}, {2, 4, 0.0598549}, {2, 5, 0.0490927}, {2, 6, 
  0.0328169}, {2, 7, 0.0154528}, {2, 8, -0.00391657}, {2, 
  9, -0.0278968}, {2, 10, -0.0507444}, {3, 1, 0.0484558}, {3, 2, 
  0.0589233}}
```

I am struggling with the `BarChart3D`. I would like to have something like that :

http://blog.numerix.com/.a/6a011570f0b826970c016769008840970b-pi

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways, I give it a try. One is to use `ListPlot3D` with option `InterpolationOrder -> 0` and `Filling -> Bottom`. Here a slightly modified example from the documentation:

```
square[{{imin_, imax_}, {jmin_, jmax_}}] :=  
  Table[UnitStep[i - imin, imax - i] UnitStep[j - jmin, jmax - j], {i, 0, 20}, {j, 0, 20}]
```

and

```
ListPlot3D[
    Abs@Fourier[square[{{2, 5}, {3, 7}}]], 
    Mesh -> None, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    InterpolationOrder -> 0,  
    Filling -> Bottom
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can use `DiscretePlot3D`. You can use your data format but have to transform a bit. Here one way (optimized for reading), just extract the z-value and take (x,y) for the appropriate coordinates ("test" is your data):

```
func[i_, j_] := (Flatten @ Select[test, (#[[1]] == i && #[[2]] == j) &])[[3]]
```

and then:

```
DiscretePlot3D[
  func[i, j], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 8}, 
  ExtentSize -> Full, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

**Using `BarChart3D`**

If you *have to* use `BarChart3D` you need to pre-process the input data to a form acceptable to `BarChart3D`, i.e., a list of lists of bar heights. Since your `x` and `y` values are integers you can get an array of bar heights using `SparseArray`:

```
barchrtdata = SparseArray[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ test, Automatic, Indeterminate];

BarChart3D[barchrtdata, ChartLayout -> "Grid", BarSpacing -> {.1, .2},
  BoxRatios -> 1, ChartElementFunction -> "ProfileCube", 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", BaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]]
```

[image]

**Using `BubbleChart3D`**

Alternatively, you can use `BubbleChart3D` using a `ChartElementFunction` that produces cuboids similar to `BarChart3D`:

```
bblchrtdata = {##, 1} & @@@ test;
BubbleChart3D[bblchrtdata, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ChartElementFunction -> (ChartElementDataFunction[
      "ProfileCube"][# /. {x_, y_, {z1_, z2_}} :> {x, 
        y, {0, (z1 + z2)/2}}, ##2] &), BubbleSizes -> {.05, .05}]
```

[image]

**Using `Graphics3D`**

```
grphcsdata = {{-.15, -.5, 0} + {1, 1, 0} {##}, {.15, .5, 0} + {##}} & @@@ test;

Graphics3D[{Opacity[.7], 
  ColorData[{"Rainbow", Through@{Min, Max}@test[[All, 3]]}][#[[2, 3]]], 
 ChartElementDataFunction["DoubleProfileCube"][Transpose[#], {}]} & /@ grphcsdata, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I haven´t had in mind BubbleChart3D... looks really good!